# C++ execute python file using ShellExecuteA

Tags: python, c++, shell

So im trying to execute a python file (no console) using C++ shellapi.h ShellExecuteA but it wont work and return a value 42 if i do

```
int value = ShellExecuteA(nullptr,"open",path.c_str(),nullptr,nullptr, SW_HIDE );
```

and return (error 2) if i use GetLastError(); from errhandlingapi.h
here is the entire function in C++

```cpp
void mainwindow::make_projectsave(){

ofstream ofFile(PATH + string("depozitdir\\info.txt"));
string line;

for(int nr = 0;nr<scazator.size();nr++){

    line = column1[nr] +"  "+ column2[nr] +"  "+ column3[nr] + "  "+ scazator[nr] +"  "+ column4[nr] + "\n";
    ofFile<<line;}


string dirname = std::string(namevector[2]);
string name = std::string(namevector[0]);
namevector.clear();
ofFile<< "=filename->" +name+"\n";
ofFile<< "=dir->" +dirname+"\n";
ofFile.close();
string path = PATH + "makesave.pyw";

ShellExecuteA(nullptr,"open",path.c_str(),nullptr,nullptr, SW_HIDE ); // doesnt work...
```

what it  does it stores some info to the file info.txt and then calls the python file (which doesnt work) so it makes an excel file.

Comment: Check out the MSDN for the meaning of different errors. For a good question here, you should also extract and create a [mcve]. In particular, your code is not compilable and it's also unclear whether this is specific to Python or not. BTW: Consider not using the *A functions but the *W ones instead for better internationalization. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it make the file you want to execute .py , instead of .pyw